# HTML CSS style height:100% Works fine in chrome but not in IE or Firefox [becoming crazy!]

Tags: html, css, browser, styles, compatibility

i have an index page that navigates via opening the url inside a div

In chrome works fine but not with any other browser.

the code is the following:

```
<!-- This is a part of index.php who redirects the browser to another site inside a div.-->

   <div  style="width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden;">
    <object type="text/html" data="http://*****.com/home.php" style="width:100%; height:100%; margin:1%;">
    </object>
</div>
```

How can i solve it, what am i doing wrong!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Height is relative to the parent, so you need to add height:100% to body and html to get it to work.  Not sure why it works in Chrome...

Answer (score 0):

add this at the begining of your css it will reset the default parameter of the browser like margin on main elements :

```
/* CSS reset */
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you `header.css` you want to declare:

```
html, body { height: 100% }
```

on line 7 of it you just put the width

Comment: Have done it, but unfortunatelly the problem persists. Thanks !

Comment: Seems strange... di you refresh your browser cache?

Comment: the point is that i header.css is not the main css , im using another one, i did the same in it and it runs perfectly, thanks.